# No response from Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to register user via email and password on Android phone.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Firebase register new user (I can see it in Firebase -> Authentication) but I don"t get any reponse from Firebase when it succesfully registered new user. No Success, no failure. It used to work correctlly. How I can get to know what is wrong? How I can print error message or something?

I did some changes with my google-services but I reverted it and it should work

Comment: Have you added the [appropriate listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start#sign_up_new_users)?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the .createUserWithEmailAndPassword() operation? If you did, show us the corresponding code.

Comment: addOnCompleteListener was missing. A bit strange it used to work without that listener :)
Thanks